# Проблема с передачей данных в фреймах

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет. Сломал всю голову уже.

Нужно, чтобы по клику кнопку в фрейме 3 в объекте  атрибут src принимал нужное мне значение "1.jpg".
Почему не работает? Перелопатил кучу сайтов, делал по примерам, делал методом тыка, делал через сами знаете что. Не работает. Ну ни в какую.

Это главная страница:

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Страница</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
</script>

</head>

<frameset rows=40%,60%">
<frame src="frame1.html" name="frame1" noresize=true>
   <frameset id="frameset1" cols=50%,50%>
   <frame src="frame2.html" name="frame2" noresize=true>
   <frame src="frame3.html" name="frame3" noresize=true>
   </frameset>
</frameset>

</html>
```

2й фрейм в котором кнопка:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function ChangeImg() {
    parent.frame3.document.form1.getElementById("img1").src = "1.jpg";
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p align="center">FRAME 2</p>
<input type="button" name="b1" value="Кнопочка" OnClick="ChangeImg()">

</body>

</html>
```

Фрейм с картинкой:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
</script>

</head>

<body>
<p align="center">FRAME 3</p>
<form name="form1">
<img src="121212121" id="img1">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А вы пробовали инструменты разработчика (developer tools) открывать? Там бы вы сразу увидели ошибку, что `form1.getElementById` не существует.

Comment: На кой использовать устаревшие теги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `getElementById` есть только у `document`. Что логично, т.к. `id` должен быть уникальным в рамках всего документа.

Так что код должны быть такой

```js
parent.frame3.document.getElementById("img1").src = "1.jpg";
```